# Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata. (Apple reject) Unable to install the app on iPad

Tags: ios, xcode

Apple reject my app with Message:

> Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata
>
> We were unable to install the app on iPad. The
>   UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a
>   way that the app will not install on an iPad .
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
>   key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your
>   app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device.
>   Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are
>   required and false if they must not be present on the device.
>
> Resources
>
> Please review the [Technical Q&A 1397: Understanding the
>   UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1397/_index.html) for information on the
>   UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.
>
> You may also wish to review the dictionary keys table in the
>   ["Declaring the Required Device Capabilities"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW5) section of the App
>   Programming Guide for iOS.

App has Deployment info, Devices: Universal.

I tested app on iPad 2 Wi-Fi (model: A1397), iOS 9.3.5 (13G36). And different iPhones. App works correct.

There is following value of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in file-info:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

There was not problem with **armv7** at previous releases .

At [webpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) wrote, that **armv7** is supported all modern devices.

What I need to do with UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities parameter?

Comment: Have you got any embedded Targets with a different, more restrictive, value?

Comment: There are two targets with same value.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the **armv7** value at info.plist file. Application successfully passed review.

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array/>
```

Comment: where did u remove this? and also please mention that are u publishing only for iPad.

Comment: I removed it at info.plist file.